# Hide the heading if mysql query is empty

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to hide a section of html if it is used to display a php/mysql query result that comes back empty. Below is the query:

```
try
{
$park_id = $_GET['park_id'];
$query2="SELECT `name` FROM  `tpf_rides` WHERE  `park_id` = $park_id AND  `top_ride` = 1 ORDER BY `name` ASC";
$result2 = $pdo->query($query2);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$output = 'Unable to pull rides.';
include 'output.html.php';
}

$output = 'Sucessfully pulled rides';
//include 'output.html.php';//
```

and the part of code used to display the results:

```
<h2>Top Attractions</h2>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($result2 as $row2): ?>

<li><h3><?php echo $row2['name']; ?></h3></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<hr>
```

There are a number of parks on the site that don't yet have top attractions - indicated by "`top_ride` = 1". Rather than have `"<h2>Top Attractions</h2>"` show up with no rides listed below I would ideally have the whole code above not show if there are no "top ride = 1" for a particular park.

Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
    <?php

       if($count = $query2->rowcount() < 1) {

       echo "No results found";
        }   else { 

 echo "<h2>Top Attractions</h2>";

    foreach($result2 as $row2) {


    if(!empty($row2['name'])) {

    echo "<li><h3>{$row2['name']}</h3></li>";

    } else {




    }


    }

}
    ?>
```

Comment: I tried the above code but got this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in /home/danville/public_html/parkindex/park.php on line 104. Sorry, I am very new to PHP and can't work this out.

Comment: Hello @Harry Beaseant : try to update the rowCount() to rowcount() and don't forget that php is case sensitive . Tell me if this work :)

Comment: The case sensitivity didn't work. I think it may be an issue with my query. As I've mentioned I'm really new to this getting by with a lot of trial and error. $query2 is looking for any attraction in the ride table with a 1 in the top_ride. This means for any park there could be up to 5 different rides being shown. DOn't know if this helps. here is the query again. $park_id = $_GET['park_id'];
$query2="SELECT `name` FROM  `tpf_rides` WHERE  `park_id` = $park_id AND  `top_ride` = 1 ORDER BY `name` ASC";
$result2 = $pdo->query($query2);

Comment: I still get this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function rowcount() on a non-object in /home/danville/public_html/parkindex/park.php on line 138"